# Can't get fixed div to stop above the footer, what am I missing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a side bar div that is fixed until a certain scroll/page height and then it becomes `position:absolute`.

My problem is that, when it loads in, it's at the right position and height, until I scroll and then it moves (partly due to the `jQuery` function). When it moves however, it makes it so it doesn't stop at the footer, but instead continues past it.

I am building this on a COS so I can't exactly recreate the problem in JSFiddle, but I can link you to the page.

**CSS**

```
/*fixed/absolute div*/
.widget-type-post_listing{
    right:0;
    width:50px;
    position:absolute;
    display;block;
    background:yellow;
    height:50px;
   }
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){
    var container = $('.widget-type-post_listing');
    var minTop = $('.header-container-wrapper').outerHeight();
    var maxTop = $('.footer-container-wrapper').offset().top - container.outerHeight(); 

    $(document).scroll(function() {
        container.css('top', Math.min( Math.max(minTop, $(document).scrollTop()), maxTop ));
    });
});
```

Here is the JS Fiddle showing a working example: **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9mp8spkd/)**. You can see that the yellow box (fixed/abso.div) will stick on page until scrolling to footer.

As I said above, to see the exact problem, visit the working page: **[Working Page](https://preview.hs-sites.com/_hcms/preview/template/multi?template_layout_id=3591379871&is_buffered_template_layout=true&portalId=494351&tc_deviceCategory=DESKTOP)**

Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: Just to be clear. Are you talking about the chat with us div. Right?

Comment: You seem to have many javascript errors if you look the console. "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).sidr is not a function", "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).equalHeight is not a function". But it's hard to debug since it's minified.

Comment: Is the code on your working page the current code? It seems that you are using other elements to determine `minTop` and `maxTop` here on SO.

Comment: @MehdiBrillaud The errors are because it doesn't load "global header" js files in the Preview/Dev mode of the framework. I don't use `equalHeight.js` or `sidr.js` on this page.

Comment: @Eddi Yes, for the most part. I am currently messing with the `minTop` value, but assume it is the code that is here on SO. The jsfiddle is just an extremely simplified sample. I will swap the code on the working page to match this one exactly.

Comment: @Lidaranis My mistake, I should have specified. I am trying to do this with the "Popular Posts" div.

Comment: What's the expected behaviour of the JSFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a div in between footer and header surrounding the yellow div 100% width position relative and then fix the max-height of that div and set it's display to inline-flex or inline-block. I think that should so the job.

```
Cover-div{
width: 100%;
display: inline-flex;
position: relative;
}
```